# build web files with maven

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, tomcat7-maven-plugin

I'm developing a simple maven web application using angular and java inside a same project.For front-end I use **webapp/resources** as the path.The problem was when I edit some javascipt/css or other static resources then I have to re-deploy the whole application.Is there a way to deploy only web files instead of re-deploying the whole app.I'm using 'tomcat7-maven-plugin' for building purpose.

thanks.

Comment: if this is for local development purposes, you can manually copy over the files. For production, it's best advised to move the entire build.

Comment: Have you tried JRebel? https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/